# Backup once when using lineinfile with loop in Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible, backup

I'm trying to update a file with lineinfile in a loop, and it makes two backup file at once. Is there a way to not make the second one?

```yaml
- name: disable kernelhints on apt install
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf
    regexp: '^.*\$nrconf{{"{"}}{{ item }}{{"}"}}.*$'
    line: '$nrconf{{"{"}}{{ item }}{{"}"}} = 0;'
    backup: true
  loop:
    - 'kernelhints'
    - 'ucodehints'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can track the loop index and calculate a boolean for `backup`

Note that this solution is far from perfect as you won't get any backup if the first iteration did not change anything or failed.

```yaml
- name: Disable kernelhints on apt install
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/needrestart/needrestart.conf
    regexp: '^.*\$nrconf{{"{"}}{{ item }}{{"}"}}.*$'
    line: '$nrconf{{"{"}}{{ item }}{{"}"}} = 0;'
    backup: "{{ it | int == 0 }}"
  loop:
    - 'kernelhints'
    - 'ucodehints'
  loop_control:
    index_var: it
```

Comment: It works, thank you! Is `int` filter really needed here? It seems `index_var` is a number.

Comment: It's a general good practice in Ansible where Jinja templating can more or less transform anything back to a string on many occasions (even though chances are low in this particular case)

Comment: Be careful. You'll get no backup at all if there are no changes on the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks @VladimirBotka . Actually, this behaviour is exactly what I need)

Comment: @VladimirBotka oh, I just got what you mean. You mean the loop iteration, not the ansible play iteration. Your answer provides good explanation of the problem. Of course this behavior is not desirable. So this answer is not a working solution. Unfortunately I have to take my vote back)

Comment: @raacer I since edited the answer (yesterday) to emphasize that point.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can 'preen' your backup files. For example, create a list of your files

```yaml
  my_backups:
    - /tmp/test.conf
```

Find all backups and delete all but the first one

```yaml
    - name: Find my backups
      find:
        paths: "{{ item|dirname }}"
        patterns: "{{ item|basename }}.*~"
      register: out
      loop: "{{ my_backups }}"
    - name: Keep the first backup only
      file:
        state: "{{ ansible_loop.last|ternary('file', 'absent') }}"
        path: "{{ item.1.path }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ out.results }}"
        - files
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.1.path }}"
        extended: true
```

---

**Notes**

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    my_backups:
      - /tmp/test.conf

  tasks:

    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/test.conf
        line: "{{ item }}"
        backup: true
      loop:
        - line2
        - line3

    - name: Find my backups
      find:
        paths: "{{ item|dirname }}"
        patterns: "{{ item|basename }}.*~"
      register: out
      loop: "{{ my_backups }}"
    - name: Keep the first backup only
      file:
        state: "{{ ansible_loop.last|ternary('file', 'absent') }}"
        path: "{{ item.1.path }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ out.results }}"
        - files
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.1.path }}"
        extended: true
```

- Example of the playbook's output

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [lineinfile] ****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=line2)
changed: [localhost] => (item=line3)

TASK [Find my backups] ***********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test.conf)

TASK [Keep the first backup only] ************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test.conf.174273.2022-12-14@08:08:01~)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test.conf.179001.2022-12-14@08:38:36~)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test.conf.178970.2022-12-14@08:38:36~)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/test.conf.174242.2022-12-14@08:08:01~)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

- The result will be

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.conf
line1
line2
line3
```

- Only the first backup will be present

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.conf.174242.2022-12-14@08\:08\:01~ 
line1
```

- The [*loop_control*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) doesn't work properly in controlling the backup. For example, given the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.conf 
line1
```

The task below

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/test.conf
        line: "{{ item }}"
        backup: "{{ ansible_loop.index == 1 }}"
      loop:
        - line2
        - line3
      loop_control:
        extended: true
```

works as expected

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] ****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=line2)
changed: [localhost] => (item=line3)
```

, creates the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.conf 
line1
line2
line3
```

, and also creates the backup on the first iteration

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.conf.170212.2022-12-14@07\:09\:41~ 
line1
```

But when you are given the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.conf 
line1
line2
```

the task also creates the file as expected

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=line2)
changed: [localhost] => (item=line3)
```

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test.conf 
line1
line2
line3
```

but no backup is created because the first iteration changes nothing.